# WiFi Adapter Not Found - Acer Laptop Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have an Aspire 3690-3970 laptop and I’m trying to get internet access.  I’m getting the following msg:

> WiFi Adapter Not Found - Acer Laptop Ubuntu 22.04.

How do I enable or get a Wifi Adapter for my laptop?

`05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01) 06:01.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)`

System information:

- Device Name candice-Aspire-3690
- Memory 2.0 GiB
- Processor Intel® Celeron(R) M CPU 520 @ 1.60GHz Graphics Intel® 945GM
- Disk Capacity 80.0 GB
- OS Name Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- OS Type 64-bit GNOME Version 42.5
- Windowing System Wayland

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `lspci`.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: When I originally bought this computer, it came with Win Vista and it had a compatible  Wi-Fi adapter.  My main problem right now appears to be getting the terminal to read or recognize the desktop which contains the b43 library.  This required library exist on the desktop, but I keep getting a msg that says it doesn't, as a matter of fact, when eliminatinf th b43 library from the search, I get a msg that says my desktop is not found.  Thanks, Shep.

Comment: One step at the time. If it has an internal WiFi card then please [edit] the question and post the exact one (the first comment indicates how to find out). Then, and only then, we can answer about what to do in order to have it working. You're already assuming 2 things (and at least one is quite wrong): 1. That it's a Broadcom; 2. That you need to be downloading firmware (b43) for Debian to install in Ubuntu (this is obviously the wrong one). But again, step by step, FIRST confirm which one, if any, you have.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: This is what others with this computer has done successfully and they now have Wi-Fi.  But they did not have a problem loading or reading files located on their desktop.  I agree that we should take this one step at a time.  The first issue in my opinion is to find out how to access the desktop from the terminal.

Comment: NO, that's NOT the issue. Your approach is the issue right now. To be clear: It's possible (but unlikely) that it has WiFi and that WiFi is one of the Broadcom ones that requires additional drivers and that specific firmware (b43). Even if everything matches what you're trying to do has NOTHING to do with accessing or not "files on the desktop" and even less with something packaged for Debian (Ubuntu is based on Debian but Ubuntu is NOT Debian). Ubuntu has all it needs for enabling those Broadcom cards in its own official repositories, (...)

Comment: (...) it's as easy as running one or two command with an alternative internet connection. Now, brand/model of the laptop is irrelevant because the same model may have been shipped with different hardware (up to 4 different WiFi cards is not unheard of). That's why, if you want help, I must insist you provide that information and meanwhile stop whatever you're doing because you're doing it wrong, no doubt about that. We are trying to save you from yourself, if it was clear by now.

Comment: @Changan: OK, I now understand.  As of now, No Wi-Fi adapter is detector is detected.  Question, if this computer was able to access the internet with Win Vista, which was many years ago, what can I do now?  What are my options?  This comment came after reading your last reply.

Comment: Please open the terminal and run `lspci` (1st comment, 14 hours ago). This will list all devices in the PCI bus. One of the lines will (hopefully) identify the WiFi card (if it has one and isn't faulty). Please [edit] the question and post that exact line (everything else is irrelevant) pasting it inside {_} (button in the editor (this is merely for aesthetics and readability but personally I'm happy with whatever way you add it to the question). Note: "No Wi-Fi adapter detect" is only in the graphical interface because it doesn't exist, it's faulty or doesn't have drivers/firmware (...)

Comment: The aforementioned command has no such limitation, if it exists and it's working it'll show it in its own line in the list. That the only thing we need to attempt to answer your question. Note 2: You can open the Terminal like any other app (search and click) or with CTRL+ALT+T.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: 05:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
06:01.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)
06:04.0 CardBus bridge: ENE Technology Inc CB-712/4 Cardbus Controller (rev 10).  Hopefully, this is what you need, but if you need something else, I have the entire lspci output.

Comment: @ChanganAuto:  Not sure if this additional information will help, but here it is anyway:  Device Name   candice-Aspire-3690
Memory            2.0 GiB
Processor            Intel® Celeron(R) M CPU 520 @ 1.60GHz
Graphics              Intel® 945GM
Disk Capacity       80.0 GB
OS Name               Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
OS Type                  64-bit
GNOME Version     42.5
Windowing System  Wayland

Comment: Broadcom indeed. Reference: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110

Comment: @ChanganAuto: This issue is resolved.  I need to connect to the internet via a USB cable.  Thank you so very much for your assistance.  I'm new to Linux as well as this forum.  I'd like you to get credit for this resolution; what is the next step?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/629981/ethernet-network-card-bcm4401-b0-no-longer-recognised

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I have acquired a Monoprice Cat5e Ethernet Patch Cable, but I'm still not able to connect to the internet.  I still need some help if possible.  Thanks, Shep

Comment: Your question is about the WiFi -> Answered. It should work provided your router is set to support 802.11b/g (at least "g" it should) but please understand everything in your laptop is too old already so things may not work with modern routers that work for 802.11n or newer. Your question about Ethernet is a NEW question, feel free to post it (and expect people to ask for a LOT of additional info). If my answer (WiFI) was useful please accept it (comment below the answer shows how).

Answer (score 1):

```
Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01) 06:01.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)
```

It can be installed in Ubuntu release with a few simple steps:

1. Get an alternative, temporary, internet connection (Ethernet, USB tethering from any Android phone or iPhone with mobile data or already connected to any WiFi AP or other).
2. Open the Terminal and run `sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer`
3. Reboot.

Reference: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110

PS - As pointed out in comments, for this cases, Ubuntu is very user friendly, a single command downloads an installs the driver/firmware. Do not attempt to follow instructions for Debian, it won't end well.

Comment: As previously commented, this issue is resolved.  You've been a great help and resource!  Thank you so very much.  I'm not sure just how to give you credit for this resolution, but I'd like to.   I just joined this forum two days ago.

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Again, thanks for all of your help.  We've finally gotten online after fixing a lot of corrupt files.  Thanks, Shep

Comment: No need to thank anyone in comments. Again, if the answer was useful please accept it, that's all.